Restricting Firestore access by service account
I have a node app that uses the firebase sdk to read/write to a firestore db.
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.12.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
  },

import admin = require('firebase-admin');
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';

const app = initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": ...,
    "private_key_id": ...,
    "private_key": ...,
    "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": ...,
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": ...
  } as any
  )
});
let db = admin.firestore();

This app is able to read/write to firestore just fine if my security rules are totally open:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     allow read: if true
     allow write: if true
    }
  }
}

However, I want to restrict read/write access only to the service account specified during app initializiation ("firebase-adminsdk-...@....iam.gserviceaccount.com").
Do I need to add anything to my security rules to restrict access just to this service account? Or is that done implicitly by firestore?


Do I need to add anything to my security rules to restrict access just to this service account?

All access to Firestore from backend or admin SDKs initialized with a service account (that is, anything but web and mobile SDKs) bypasses security rules entirely.  Rules only apply to web and mobile access using the provided SDKs for those platforms.
See also:

Does firebase-admin override firestore security rules?
Can cloud functions bypass firestore security rules


Or is that done implicitly by firestore?

Each Google Cloud product has IAM roles and permissions for various actions.  You should review the documentation to find out which of those might apply to your use case.

I found the IAM documentation undecipherable. What do I need to do to ensure that Firestore reads and writes can only be performed by the service account?

It doesn't work that way.  You can't limit access to just one service account.  What you can do is enable a service account with the appropriate permissions to do what it needs to do.  GCP IAM implements an "allowlist" not a "denylist", and it's up to you to ensure that all of your service accounts in use are permissioned the way you need.  You can't override a service account that was previously allowed by writing rules.  You should probably study GCP IAM in more detail to understand how the greater system works at a higher level: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/

Yes, it's complicated.  And necessarily so, in order to support enterprise requirements.

"What you can do is enable a service account with the appropriate permissions to do what it needs to do" -- does this imply that anyone who is not a service account (eg. the public internet) cannot access my service by default? If so, then that's what I'm looking for.

Anyone who is not using a service account is subject to your Firebase security rules, which governs anonymous access, or access using a Firebase Auth user account.  It's your responsibility to ensure those rules enforce whatever logic you want. More specifically, they should deny all access.  The rules you show now in this question are the exact opposite of full denial.
